# Python2 word input if-statement script

Tags: python, if-statement, words

Below is the script I'm trying to write.  I've made other working scripts, including simple if-statement scripts, but I wanted to experiment a bit and try making a script that relies on string inputs instead of integers or floaters.

It goes without saying that I'm still learning and won't require this to do my job, but thanks for trying if you decide to take a crack at it.  I spent about an hour with another novice coder trying out tiny adjustments.  I'm almost certain it's futile to have the input equal a string to start with, creating my strife.

```
answer = raw_input("Do you enjoy your work?\n")

print str(answer)
if answer = str("yes") :
    print "I'm happy to hear that, " + str(name)"
    print "I wonder what being a " + str(title) + " actually means."
    print "I don't have the term in my vocabulary.  I'm a machine."
    raw_input("My script is over soon.  Goodbye.\n")
else :
    print "I'm sorry to hear that, " + str(name)"
    print "I guess being a " + str(title) + " must be difficult."
    raw_input("My script is over soon.  Goodbye.\n")
```

Comment: answer == "yes". Your intention is to check for condition but you are assigning value "yes" to answer.

Comment: Oh, and this isn't the whole script, just the part that doesn't work.  If you want to test it yourself just remove the parts that say + str(name) and + str(title). 

ajkumar25 came up with the same error I've been getting all day.  Thanks for the fast reply, though!

Comment: raw_input() return as string, no need to re-str.

Comment: zoosuck's solution didn't work either, but I've implemented both of their suggestions.  Maybe we can fix it one line at a time, lol.  No wait, I'm not finished implementing zoo's fix after all..

Comment: ITS ALIVE!  Well, it's a step in the right direction.

Thank you guys so much, you've absolutely made my day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string already, so you don't have to convert it to string again. No need `str("yes")` this.

Also your intention is wrong. It must be;

```
if answer == "yes":
```

Your whole script must be like;

```
from time import sleep
answer = raw_input("Do you enjoy your work?\n")

print answer
if answer == "yes":
    print "I'm happy to hear that, " + name)"
    print "I wonder what being a " + title + " actually means."
    print "I don't have the term in my vocabulary.  I'm a machine."
    print ("My script is over soon.  Goodbye.\n")
    sleep(2)
else :
    print "I'm sorry to hear that, " + name"
    print "I guess being a " + title + " must be difficult."
    print ("My script is over soon.  Goodbye.\n")
    sleep(2)
```

Used `sleep` function from `time` module. So it'll wait which seconds do you want as you see it's 2 seconds now `sleep(2)`

Also you can use `format()` function to place like;

```
print "I'm sorry to hear that {} ".format(name)
```

It's my favorite function since it's pretty usefull, check it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format)

Comment: the title and name are inputs, so they don't need to be strung again.

Comment: @JonesCrimson True thanks for warning I forget to fix them :) But in your codes they were like it

Comment: I would rate your answer as helpful, too, if I had the reputation.

Answer (score 2):

2 things to get you up and running

```
if answer = str("yes") :
```

Is wrong this will assign a string "yes" to answer. As it is it won't run. Use

```
if answer == "yes" :
```

Also take away the unneeded quotes at the end of

```
print "I'm happy to hear that, " + str(name)"
```

instead

```
print "I'm happy to hear that, " + name
```

You should only enclose string literals in quotes and you'd usually have an even number of quotes.

The final thing is all these `str` calls aren't required if the value is already a string. It will work like this but you are doing unnecessary work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete script in it's entirety. I was stringing the inputs when I didn't have to, like an idiot.  I also had 3 typos to correct.

```
print "Hello. I'm a program made to ask generic questions and reply."
print "I'm not advanced enough to react to questions I'm asked."
print "If I had to pick a name for myself, it would be Dan."
name = raw_input("What is your name?\n")

title = raw_input("You already know what I do for work.  What is your official title?\n")

answer = raw_input("Do you enjoy your work?\n")

if answer == str("yes") :
    print "I'm happy to hear that, " + name
    print "I wonder what being a " + title + " actually means."
    print "I don't have the term in my vocabulary.  I'm a machine."
    raw_input("My script is over soon.  Goodbye.\n")
else :
    print "I'm sorry to hear that, " + name
    print "I guess being a " + title + " must be difficult."
    raw_input("My script is over soon.  Goodbye.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is right version:

```
answer = raw_input("Do you enjoy your work?\n")

print answer
if answer == "yes" : # use == to judge string equals but not =
    print "I'm happy to hear that, " + str(name)
    print "I wonder what being a " + str(title) + " actually means."
    print "I don't have the term in my vocabulary.  I'm a machine."
    raw_input("My script is over soon.  Goodbye.\n")
else :
    print "I'm sorry to hear that, " + str(name)
    print "I guess being a " + str(title) + " must be difficult."
    raw_input("My script is over soon.  Goodbye.\n")
```

In your code your `if` is wrong, you should use `==` to replace `=`.
Code like this:

```
ans = raw_input("input word:")
if ans = 'yes':
  print 'yes'
else:
  print 'no'
```

is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: The problem, on top of the ==, was that I was stringing inputs.